# Can we get the total record count and the first record only in the same eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

Can we get the total record count and the first record only in the same eloquent query?

I know we can get the total records via below eloquent queries:

```
1. Model::count();

2. Collection Method
   Model::all()->count();
```

And we can get the first record like this:

```
Model::first();
```

I have one solution for the same i.e.

```
$data = Model::all();

1. $count = count($data);
2. $count = $data->count();
```

And for the first row/data

```
1. $firstRecord = $data[0];
2. $firstRecord = $data->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a query, Laravel under the hood, creates a new instance of the query builder with the method [`newQuery()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L955), this query can be reused as much times as you want

```php
$query = Model::where('...')->whereHas('...')->orderBy('...');

[
  'count' => $query->count(),
  'collection' => $query->get(),
  'first' => $query->first()
]
```

Something similar happens with the `LengthAwarePaginator`'s `paginate()` method. Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L698).

Comment: Amazing, yet I'm asking the same question will it hit the two queries or can pull the data in one query ?. I am asking these things at the Database level.

Comment: No it will execute 2 queries